# Stop fgetc from repeating the loop based on the number of input + 1?

Tags: c, loops

My problem is, depending on how many character I input, my code loops based on that plus 1.
For example, 5 character + 1, my code loops 6 times.

I've tried using different alternatives such as getchar, scanf but i'm sitting in fgetc, simply because I prefer it.

The problem code is:

```
char decision = ' ';
printf("input data: ");
decision = fgetc(stdin);

while (checkChar(&decision) != 1)
    {
    printf("Please input a valid choice, 1 or 0\n");
    decision = fgetc(stdin);
    }
```

Note, checkChar simply checks to see if the char is 1 or 0, very basic.
For example, if I inputted 4 it would result in:
Please input a valid choice, 1 or 0
Please input a valid choice, 1 or 0
Please input a valid choice, 1 or 0
Please input a valid choice, 1 or 0
Please input a valid choice, 1 or 0

I've come to a solution of using:

```
while(fgetc(stdin) != '\n')
```

But its not exactly what i'd call tidy. I was just wondering if there's a better method?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's not only not tidy, it will result in an endless loop if you reach end of file.

Comment: @JamesKanze: It's basically impossible for an SO question in C or C++ to contain correct I/O logic... :-(

Comment: @KerrekSB If the poster knew enough to be able to write input correctly, he probably wouldn't have to post a question here.  (Input can be exceedingly difficult, because of all of the possible error conditions you have to check for.)

Comment: Note that `fgetc()` returns `int`, **not** `char`.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all the Input! I've decided to try a method that takes everything into a single string and then i'll scanf that string and see what I can make from that. The only limitation obviously being if the user enters a string over the limit of the actual string, but i'll work one a fix for that. I might set the string for length 21 and if the character at point 21 isn't NULL then continue but if it is, spit out a too long error. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JamesKanze: Well, yes, but I think what irks me even more is that most people who have I/O problems don't really care at all about getting it right. They'll accept any small quickfix that solves one single problem in the case of their ideal input, and never bother to think about whether the code is robust in the face of more general input. In that regard, people seem to be far sloppier when doing I/O than when solving most other types of problems... :-(

Comment: @KerrekSB That's because it's not as much fun.  There's no real analysis involved, just writing a lot of additional tests.  And the resulting code is rarely beautiful.  (On the other hand: why do so many people write things like `while ( !input.eof() )`?  That has never been right, and I've never seen a book which suggests it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not too clear what you want—it sounds somewhat like
you want to really read a character at a time, which isn't
really possible in C++.  (You'd need a separate library, like
curses, for this.)  Input from a keyboard is *always* line
oriented, and so you probably need to input a line at a time.
This sort of thing belongs in a separate function, e.g.:

```
char
getDecision( std::istream& source, char const* legalDecisions )
{
    char results = '\0';
    std::string line;
    while ( results == '\0' && std::getline( source, line) ) {
        if ( ! line.empty() 
                && std::strchr( legalDecisions, line[0] ) != NULL ) {
            results = line[0];
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

In practice, you probably want to do a lot more processing in
the loop above.  Skipping leading whitespace, verifying that
there is only the command, etc.  But the above should give the
basic idea.  (Assuming that the standard line oriented input is
acceptable.  Otherwise, you need curses.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you say C++, do it like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

std::cout << "Input data: ";
char decision = '\0';

for (std::string d; std::getline(std::cin, d); )
{
    if (d == "1" || d == "0") { decision = d[0]; break; }
    std::cout << "Please input a valid choice ('0' or '1'): ";
}

if (d == '\0')
{
    std::cout << "Premature end of input, aborting.\n";
    std::exit(1);
}
```

Comment: I find a `for` here rather confusing.  A `while` with both conditions would be more readable (IMHO).  And hiding a `break` somewhere out at the end of a line is a definite no-no.  (I'd argue that using a `break` to get out of a loop is bad programming practice.  But if you do, it must be clearly visible on a line by itself.)

Comment: And you don't really want to abort the program in case of end of file, do you?  (Actually, you might, but the input function is not the place to make this decision.  Either return `'\0'`, and let the caller decide, or throw an exception.)  And you generally don't want to call `exit` in C++, because this means that destructors of local variables aren't executed.  (None of which is relevant to the original question, but if you're going to give example code, give good examples.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: Mostly good points, and I meant this as a code fragment rather than a complete program (hence no `main`!), but I do would like to stick with the `for` loop. I'm arriving at the opinion that *every* loop is in some sense a `for` loop, and I hate leaking variables into the ambient scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scanf()` for your case

```
int decision, c;
char tmp;

printf("input data: ");

while ((c = (scanf(" %d%c", &decision, &tmp)!=2 || !isspace(tmp)))
        || (decision<0 || decision>1))
    {
    printf("Please input a valid choice, 1 or 0\n", c);
    if(c) scanf("%*[^\n]");
    }
```

this line:

```
if(c) scanf("%*[^\n]");
```

allows to clean your stdin in case you have entered non numeric charachter in your input

Comment: Thanks for that! I tried using that and it worked for clearing the buffer, except when it came to looping and re-inputting the data, it just wasn't assigning my variable a value for some reason. But i've found a method that works better anyway as commented on my post. Thanks for the help, This was the first time i've ever come across such a complex scanf() statement, it was actually quite interesting to see

Answer (score 0):

I've messed around with this quite a bit and i've figured out how to do it decently, however this method only works if your not planning on input redirection of any kind, since you'll definitely run into problems. 
Basically You want to read the line using a string, such as: char buffer[21]. 
Then you going to want to read the data into the line using fgets: fgets(buffer, 21, stdin).

Then after you've done that have an if statement directly after that says if 
buffer[19] != '\0' that do: rewind(stdin); 
   ~ This clears the stdin (basically) but causes problems for redirection. Thanks!

After that use: sscanf(buffer, "%c", &myChar) To get the input.

Thats about it, Thanks for all the help everyone! this took my way too long. hehe.